# Odd CSS Scrolling issue, can't scroll to top left

Tags: css

I have a div inside a div and I would like to be able to scroll the inner div around. The outer div is the viewport for the inner one. The inner dive is centered vertically and horizontally and the outer div is setup with `overflow:auto` so scrolling kicks in if needed.

When the inner div is larger than the outer and I need to scroll I can get to the bottom right just fine, but I can't get to the top left.

[Here](http://justinzaun.com/cards/) is a copy of what I've got so far. Change the size to `Force Issue` to make the inner div big.

**CSS** - 
The width, height, margin-top and margin-left of #Stack are set via javascript.

```
/* The Stack */
#StackWrapper
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 330px;
    right: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#Stack
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-image: url('../images/stripes.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DTD declaration is set inside the body (and not done correctly) along with your stylesheets.

DTD Delcaration should be  above the  tag.

Doing this can clear up some issues with quirks mode or things not positioning correctly.

To correct the positioning you should change the following lines of css

```
element.style { (set by jquery for the selection )
 height: 768px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 1024px;
}
#Stack {
 background-image: url("../images/stripes.png");
 border: 1px solid black;
 position: absolute;
}
```

You have to remember that everything should have a 0 margin and padding so it starts at the top left and ends at the bottom right. Your margins where causing cut off.

You may want to look into jquery to position the scroll bars to the middle if you want it to be centered.

Quick JQuery to scroll your div to the center

```
$("div#StackWrapper").scrollLeft(width/2);
$("div#StackWrapper").scrollTop(height/2);
```

Comment: I fixed the DTD, dumb mistake on my part. As for the rest, I need to top 50%, left 50% and negative margins to center the div in the wrapper if its smaller than the wrapper. I don't see how that effects the scrolling though, `overflow:auto` should see that something is outside the bounding box and let me scroll.

Comment: change it to margin: auto and add the jquery scroll. When I remove the neg margins and top/left it works fine for me.

Comment: well, this fixed the scrolling issue. It seems overflow only works to the right an bottom, not to the left or right (with neg margins). When the inner div is smaller than the outer div setting the margins to auto center the inner div  horizontally, but not vertically.